# mysql vb.net web.config errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using  vs2010 and mysql database. Everything works fine in debug mode on my pc but when i uploaded the files to godaddy, i get this error 
    "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

here's my web.config code -\

```
        <configuration>
<connectionStrings>

</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <membership>
    <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  </profile>

  <roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
   </providers>
  </roleManager>

  </system.web>

 <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="iisstart.htm" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
 </system.webServer>
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.3.6.0" newVersion="6.4.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>

 </configuration>
```

Comment: Did you upload the MySQL.Data.dll assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upload the MySQL.Data.dll to bin folder. or in the references folder highlight the assembly and set [copy local property = true] which will auto copy that assembly to the published folder. for consistency its better to put all 3rd party assemblies in separate folder and reference them from that folder.

hope this help!